# Can I say "You have had bad marks last week"

Tags: grammar

Is it right to say

> You **have had** bad marks last week

in the meaning "for the period of the last week"?

And what is the difference between first one and this

> You **had** bad marks last week

?

Comment: Related question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-have-had

Comment: This is a completed action in the past,so the present perfect makes no sense.Hence,you need to use past simple(had).

Answer (score 2):

Even though both "had" and "have had" can refer to things in the past they imply different things. Before I get to your example about "last week", consider this example using "*this week*"...

> I have had difficult homework assignments this week.

This says that you received homework that was difficult *this* week, but because you used "have had" it could refer to a *series* of difficult assignments that are possibly even *ongoing*, as the week is not over! Similarly, if you said "*we have had heavy rain this week*" it does not exclude the possibility that you may have heavy rain again tomorrow.

But if you instead say:

> I had difficult homework assignments this week.

This puts your assignments clearly in the past. It implies that the assignments have finished.

In your example, you refer to "last week". Last week is clearly in the past, so you don't need to add any other needless words to show that it has ended.

> I had difficult homework assignments last week.

This is sufficient. It makes no sense to say "*I have had difficult homework assignments last week*" because "have" implies it is ongoing when it isn't.

What I must say in conclusion though is that your sentence may be incorrect for other reasons.

> You have had bad marks last week.

I find this sentence incorrect because "marks" are something you receive *after* you hand in a piece of work. They are the results of something you did previously. So you may have done the work *last* week but only received the marks *this* week. Also, your marks stay with you, so they are not really affected by the passage of time. If you receive a qualification you always continue to say "I *have* a qualification - you don't say "I *had* it", because that would imply you lost it! So I would prefer it if you said *either*:

> You **had** bad marks last week.

Which would mean that you *received* the bad marks last week, or:

> You **have** bad marks **for** last week.

Which would mean you have received bad marks for the work you did the previous week.

Comment: "Have had" is not past tense ; it's present perfect tense.

Comment: @khan Quite right, I explained that incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

What do you want it to mean? 
I got bad marks last week.

Because even with the tense changed your sentence doesn't (at least to me) make sense.

It should be:
I got bad/lowers marks on  my test last week.

Or simply: I got a bad  grade last week.

Marks: British

Points/grade: Usually American.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with "I got bad marks last week". It might mean in a test; it might mean in a whole series of essays or labs.

Comment: I got bad marks last week is what I've used. The person had used:you had/have had bad marks last week".